# how to active dropdown on click on checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox, laravel-5

I am new in Laravel Framework and new in jquery.
[image]

i am facing one problem. i want by default all the selectboxes are disabled.It will be active only when click on Checkbox i.e. when user click on skin care checkbox its corresponding select box will active and when user click on Hair checkbox its corresponding select box will active.
My html code as below:-

```
enter code here
<div class="div_img_part-2"> 
    <span class="img_part_class-2"><img src="img/skin-care-bbeauty-tip1.png"></span>
    <span class="text_part_class-2">
    <span class="check-box">
        <input type="checkbox" name="name"/>Skin Care</span>
    </span>
    <select class="selectpicker" >
        <option>Salon</option>
        <option>Mobile beautician</option>      
        <option>Both</option>
    </select>
 </div>
```

Note:- The above code later on i will implement through Foreach loop. So please provide me jquery code according to Foreach

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/p4h9bva6/

Comment: Dear Rayon . It looks like static i will be more interesting in dynamic Part

Comment: Dear Kunal, How do we evaluate dynamic elements from your code ? How much code have you shared ? When you say _dynamic_, what do you mean by that ? Are you trying to get the `select` element based on the pattern in which it exist in the `DOM` ?

Comment: @kunal before anyone can help in your code you should ready your final code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this jQuery code. If you are using **bootstrap selectpicker** then use `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');` for refresh selectpicker so that take effect of **disabled** attrinute otherwise remove that line from code. See my [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/sojitrar88/unr6hqnb/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".div_img_part-2 .selectpicker").attr("disabled",true);
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
                $(".check-box input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function () {
                    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
                        $(this).parents(".div_img_part-2").find(".selectpicker").removeAttr("disabled");
                        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
                    }else{
                        $(this).parents(".div_img_part-2").find(".selectpicker").attr("disabled",true);
                        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
                    }
                });
        });
```

Comment: Rakesh. I am facing one more problem i have stored data in session when i get back to that page above shown my checkbox are show selected but my dropdown becomes deactivated . I also want that checkbox is selected corresponds select box also activated. can you help please

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you,

As per your HTML,

```
<div class="div_img_part-2"> 
    <span class="img_part_class-2"><img src="img/skin-care-bbeauty-tip1.png"></span>
    <span class="text_part_class-2">
    <span class="check-box">
       <input type="checkbox" name="name"/>Skin Care</span>
    </span>
    <select class="selectpicker" >
        <option>Salon</option>
        <option>Mobile beautician</option>      
        <option>Both</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Jquery,

```
 $('select').attr('disabled', true); //By default all the select box will be disabled
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(){

     if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
         $(this).parents().parents().find('select').attr('disabled', false);
     }else{
         $(this).parents().parents().find('select').attr('disabled', true);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
  
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
         $(this).parents().parents().find('select').attr('disabled', false);
     }else{
         $(this).parents().parents().find('select').attr('disabled', true);
     }
  
}); 

  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div_img_part-2"> 
    <span class="img_part_class-2"><img src="img/skin-care-bbeauty-tip1.png"></span>
    <span class="text_part_class-2">
    <span class="check-box">
        <input type="checkbox" class="skin" name="name"/>Skin Care</span>
    </span>
    <select id="skin" name="skin" class="selectpicker" disabled >
        <option>Salon</option>
        <option>Mobile beautician</option>      
        <option>Both</option>
    </select>
 </div>
```